# Ruby http redirection to different subdomain with authentication

Tags: ruby, http

I am attempting to scrape the source data of a particular URL using ruby. To begin, I am using `Net::http.new` to create the http object and then using `http.post` to pass along the appropriate login data. This works as intended and responds with the appropriate session cookies.

After logging in, and adding the session cookie data to the headers, I then try to access the particular page that I want to scrape. The server responds with a 302 request to an aspx URL on a different subdomain, accompanied with a query string ie. `sub.domain.com/path/blah.aspx?md5=jdj456bnn`. When I try to load that subdomain using the same technique as I used before, I am met with a user not authorized 302. does anyone know the proper way to load that relocation, or what I could be missing here?

Comment: Are you adding the cookies to the subdomain headers too? Also have you looked with a browser network debugger like Firebug or the Chrome debugger what is really sent? Usually those debuggers will give you some good clues on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible a session cookie is being set during the redirect, but your code isn't maintaining it.

"[net-http-cheat-sheet](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet)" might show how to deal with it, or, look into using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org), which will [manage them](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/CookieJar.html) for you using a cookie jar.